# Run liquibase with changelog xml as stream input

Tags: java, dynamic, liquibase, changelog

I've a requirement of creating liquibase changelog which has all the required changeset at runtime and run liquibase with that dynamically created changelog stream.

I know we can have static changelog xml files and feed them to run liquibase.

I wanted to know if there is a way in which I can load this dynamic changelog xml and run the liquibase?

Comment: What problem you are trying to solve with such approach? It is possible to implement your own changelog reader and writer: https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/display/CONTRIB/ChangeLogParser / https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/display/CONTRIB/ChangeLogSerializer but your usecase looks really unusual, probably it is possible to do it other way.

Comment: Our use case is like we are trying dynamic entity creation for user specific data. We'll have a set of changesets which would be handled by a master changelog xml file. But for dynamic entity creation we want to achieve it programmatically without restarting the application. Here we want to create changeset xml as stream and run liquibase with the it instead of the physical file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same requirement, I created a new resource accessor that loads a json string (is the same for xml)

```
public class Main {

private class StreamResourceAccessor extends AbstractResourceAccessor {
    private String json;
    public StreamResourceAccessor(String jsonString) {
        super();
        this.json = jsonString;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<InputStream> getResourcesAsStream(String name) throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        Set<InputStream> returnSet = new HashSet<>();
        returnSet.add(stream);
        return returnSet;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> list(String arg0, String arg1, boolean arg2, boolean arg3, boolean arg4) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ClassLoader toClassLoader() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, LiquibaseException {
    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("user","postgres");
    props.setProperty("password","");
    //props.setProperty("ssl","true");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);

    Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
    String jsonText = "{\"databaseChangeLog\":[{\"preConditions\":[{\"runningAs\":{\"username\":\"postgres\"}}]},{\"changeSet\":{\"id\":\"1\",\"author\":\"nvoxland\",\"changes\":[{\"createTable\":{\"tableName\":\"person\",\"columns\":[{\"column\":{\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":\"int\",\"autoIncrement\":true,\"constraints\":{\"primaryKey\":true,\"nullable\":false},}},{\"column\":{\"name\":\"firstname\",\"type\":\"varchar(50)\"}},{\"column\":{\"name\":\"lastname\",\"type\":\"varchar(50)\",\"constraints\":{\"nullable\":false},}},{\"column\":{\"name\":\"state\",\"type\":\"char(2)\"}}]}}]}},{\"changeSet\":{\"id\":\"2\",\"author\":\"nvoxland\",\"changes\":[{\"addColumn\":{\"tableName\":\"person\",\"columns\":[{\"column\":{\"name\":\"username\",\"type\":\"varchar(8)\"}}]}}]}},{\"changeSet\":{\"id\":\"3\",\"author\":\"nvoxland\",\"changes\":[{\"addLookupTable\":{\"tableName\":\"person\",\"existingTableName\":\"person\",\"existingColumnName\":\"state\",\"newTableName\":\"state\",\"newColumnName\":\"id\",\"newColumnDataType\":\"char(2)\",}}]}}]}";

    Main main = new Main();
    ResourceAccessor resourceAccessor = main.new StreamResourceAccessor(jsonText);

    Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("hello.json", resourceAccessor, database);
    try {
        Contexts context = new Contexts();
        liquibase.update(context);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

}
```